# Download images from URL and add to array as image

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

So this is what I am trying to do:

> 1. Query from `Parse.com` (`PFFile` to array - strings stored in array as .png link)
> 2. Download the images from array using [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) to a array of images
> 3. Set the first image to a `UIImageView`.
> 4. When tapping the `UIImageView`, I want to change to the next image.

**The problem is that the image doesn't show up until i tap the `UIImageView`, and when I tap to try change the image, the same UIImage is showing all the time.**

This is what my ViewController code looks like:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var userFile = [PFFile]()
    var createdAt = [NSDate]()
    var objID = [String]()

    var countInt = 0

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imageArray: [UIImageView] = []
    let imageToArray = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageToArray.frame.size = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)

        queryStory()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func downloadImages() {
        if (countInt <= userFile.count - 1){
            imageToArray.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: userFile[countInt].url!)!)
            countInt = countInt + 1
            imageArray.insert(imageToArray, atIndex: 0)
            print("Image downloaded. Current count: \(imageArray.count)")
            self.downloadImages()
        }
        else{
            print("no more items")
            countInt = 0
            setImage()
        }

    }

    func setImage() {
        imageView.image = imageArray[countInt].image
        countInt = countInt + 1
        print("setImage set")
    }

    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
    {
        print("tapped")

        if (countInt <= imageArray.count - 1){
            imageView.image = nil
            print("set new image")
            imageView.image = imageArray[countInt].image
            countInt = countInt + 1
        }
        else{
            print("no more items")
        }
    }

    func queryStory(){
        self.userFile.removeAll()
        self.objID.removeAll()
        self.createdAt.removeAll()

        let query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                // Success fetching objects

                print("Post count:", posts!.count)

                for post in posts! {

                    if let imagefile = post["userFile"] as? PFFile {
                        self.userFile.append(post["userFile"] as! PFFile)
                        self.objID.append(post.objectId!)
                        self.createdAt.append(post.createdAt!)
                    }
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    print("Done")
                    self.downloadImages()
                }

                print("Uploaded files count: ", self.userFile.count)
            }
            else{
                print(error)

                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Error"
                alert.message = error?.localizedDescription
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alert.show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been messing around trying to fix this for a few hours now - but still can't.

This is the full output after I tap the UIImage:

```
Post count: 8
Uploaded files count:  8
Post count: 8
Uploaded files count:  8
Done
Image downloaded. Current count: 1
Image downloaded. Current count: 2
Image downloaded. Current count: 3
Image downloaded. Current count: 4
Image downloaded. Current count: 5
Image downloaded. Current count: 6
Image downloaded. Current count: 7
Image downloaded. Current count: 8
no more items
setImage set
tapped
set new image
```

EDIT: Weird... When I run `print(imageArray.description)` in the `tapGesture` function, I get this output: http://pastebin.com/H0u97pz5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that imageToArray is a constant. Try:

```
func downloadImages() {
    if (countInt <= userFile.count - 1){
        var imageToInsert = UIImageView()
        imageToInsert.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: userFile[countInt].url!)!)
        countInt = countInt + 1
        imageArray.insert(imageToInsert, atIndex: 0)
        print("Image downloaded. Current count: \(imageArray.count)")
        self.downloadImages()
    }
    else{
        print("no more items")
        countInt = 0
        setImage()
    }
```

Comment: Take a look now, added 2 outputs.

Comment: OK, so the else branch is executed alright. If you tap again, do you get another "tapped" in the console? (I'm curious since `userInteractionEnabled = NO` in the additional output you provided)

Comment: Yes, when I tap again i get another "tapped" in the console. But take a look at the new output I added: http://pastebin.com/H0u97pz5 - This is the array description where the images are stored. They all look the same?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I didn't notice. That's interesting - looks like all images are the same. Can you change the print statement in `handleTap` to `print("set new image: \(countInt)")` to see if it counts up properly at each tap?

Comment: Tried it and it counts up properly: `Post count: 8
Uploaded files count:  8
Post count: 8
Done
Image downloaded. Current count: 1
Image downloaded. Current count: 2
Image downloaded. Current count: 3
Image downloaded. Current count: 4
Image downloaded. Current count: 5
Image downloaded. Current count: 6
Image downloaded. Current count: 7
Image downloaded. Current count: 8
downloadImages: no more items
setImage set
tapped
set new image: 1
tapped
set new image: 2
tapped
set new image: 3
tapped
set new image: 4
tapped
set new image: 5
tapped
set new image: 6` But the image does not change at all.

Comment: I think the problem is that `imageToArray` is a constant - you keep inserting the same thing into the array over and over. The image changes, but is stored at the same location every time and overwrites the previous one. Try using a local variable in `downloadImages` instead.

Comment: Hm how do you mean exactly? Move the `let imageToArray = UIImageView()` inside the `downloadImages`?

Comment: YEA! It works now, thanks! :) But problem - the `setImage` func gets runned - because i get print in output, but the image doesn't show up until i tap the image? How come?

Comment: Yes, that is strange - the only difference between `setImage` and `handleTap` is that you set the image to `nil` first in `handleTap`(why?). What happens if you do the same in `setImage`?

Comment: I tried to copy the `handleTap` func and paste in `setImage` func, but the image does still not show up until i tap the `UIImageView`

Comment: Have you checked that there's nothing wrong with the URL for the first image (just to be sure that there actually is an image to show...)

Comment: Yes, I have checked all the images. If i comment out the `setImage` func and just tap the `UIImageView`, it show up the first image..

Comment: OK. Try calling `imageView.setNeedsDisplay()` at the end of the `setImage` function.

Comment: Tried adding it below the `countInt = countInt + 1`, but nothing is happening.

Comment: ...and you didn't forget to uncomment the call to `setImage`? ;) BTW: When you say that it shows the first image when you tap, is it really the first or the second image that is shown? Looking at the console output above, it should be the second image (with index 1)

Comment: I did uncomment the call to `setImage`, yes :D
And yea, it's the second image, not the first one.

Comment: Uh, I'm running out of ideas... I get the impression that just assigning a new image to imageView doesn't refresh the drawing of the image but for some reason when you tap, a refresh is carried out automagically. I may be totally wrong here, and I don't know what to do about it anyway. Sorry...

Comment: Very well, i'll try figure something out.. Thank you so much for helping me - I will accept your answer now! :)

Comment: Thank you, and good luck. I will let you know if I get a good idea. Also, if you find the solution please post it - one day I may end up in similar situation myself...

Comment: Thanks - and sure thing, will do!

Comment: Hi again, I slept on it an I have a theory: The `downloadImages`function is dispatched in `queryStory`and executes after the drawing cycle has completed. You need some event to trigger a new drawing cycle, which is what happens when you tap. If you remove the dispatch - will the first image show?

Comment: That did not work either.. And still skipping the first image also when tapping..